# SVG not scaling on Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, svg, internet-explorer-11

I have a list of 4 inline SVGs, each with the same height but different widths. Looks like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="">
      <svg version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 89 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
        <path d="M0.5,47.7C1,24.6,22.2,4.3,45.4,5c11.2-0.5,21.6,4.3,30,11.2C71.7,20.3,68,24.3,64,28c-10.3-7-24.8-9-35.1-0.9 c-14.7,10.1-15.3,34-1.2,44.9c13.6,12.4,39.5,6.3,43.3-12.7c-8.6-0.2-17.1,0-25.7-0.3c0-5.1,0-10.3,0-15.3c14.4,0,28.6,0,43,0 c0.9,12.1-0.8,24.8-8.1,34.8C69.1,94.1,46.6,98.7,29.1,92C11.4,85.3-1,66.7,0.5,47.7z"/>
      </svg>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="">
      <svg version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 84 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
        <path d="M62.8,24.3c-8.2,0-12.6,4.1-19.1,4c-6.5,0.1-10.9-4-19.1-4c-6.6,0-14.9,4-18.7,9.9c-7,10.8-6.3,22.5-3.4,34.6 C5.7,81.7,17,97.5,25.9,97.5c7.3,0,10.6-4,17.8-4c7.1,0,10.4,4,17.6,4c8.2,0,18.1-13.5,22.3-25.6C75.5,68.7,70,60.7,70,52.2 c0-8.4,4.3-14.9,10.9-18.6C76.8,28.2,69.1,24.3,62.8,24.3L62.8,24.3z M60.6,2.5C48.7,3.8,39.9,13.7,40.7,25 C52.5,23.8,61.2,13.8,60.6,2.5L60.6,2.5z"/>
      </svg>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="">
      <svg version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 99 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
        <path d="M61.9,21.2v19.6l6.8,4.3c0.2,0.1,0.6,0.1,0.8,0l29.4-19.8c0-2.3-2.2-4-3.4-4H61.9z"/>
        <path d="M61.9,48.1l6.2,4.3c0.9,0.6,1.9,0,1.9,0C69.1,53,99,33.1,99,33.1v36c0,3.9-2.5,5.6-5.3,5.6H61.9L61.9,48.1 L61.9,48.1z"/>
        <path d="M29.6,39c-2.1,0-3.8,1-5.1,3c-1.3,2-1.9,4.6-1.9,7.9c0,3.3,0.6,6,1.9,7.9c1.3,1.9,2.9,2.9,4.9,2.9 c2.1,0,3.8-0.9,5-2.8c1.2-1.9,1.8-4.5,1.8-7.9c0-3.5-0.6-6.2-1.8-8.1C33.3,40,31.7,39,29.6,39z"/>
        <path d="M0,11.3v76.5L58.3,100V0L0,11.3z M39,62.5c-2.5,3.2-5.7,4.9-9.6,4.9c-3.9,0-7-1.6-9.4-4.7 c-2.4-3.1-3.6-7.2-3.6-12.3c0-5.3,1.2-9.6,3.7-12.9c2.5-3.3,5.7-4.9,9.8-4.9c3.8,0,7,1.6,9.3,4.7c2.4,3.1,3.6,7.3,3.6,12.4 C42.7,55,41.5,59.2,39,62.5z"/>
      </svg>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="">
      <svg version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 126 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
        <path d="M120.1,29.2h-9.6c-1.1,0.4-2.2,0.4-3,0.7c-3.3,0.7-32.9,24-35.1,29.6c-0.4,1.8,0,21.1,0.4,23.7 c1.8,0.4,16.3,0,18.9,0.4l-0.4,5.9c-2.6-0.4-20.7,0-30.7,0c-5.2,0-22.2,0.7-27,0.4l1.1-5.5c3-0.4,14.4,0.4,17-2.2 c1.1-1.5,0.7-19.2,0.4-22.6c-1.1-3.3-27.4-35.9-34-41.4H0.3V10h59.2v0.7c0,0,0,0,0.4,0l-0.4,1.5v6.3H41.7 C49.9,30.3,61,44.4,66.1,51.1l24-21.8H76.1l-1.8-8.1h51.4l-0.4,0.7l0,0l-3.7,5.5l0,0L120.1,29.2z"/>
      </svg>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In my CSS I set the list items to display inline like so:

```
ul {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1rem 0;
}
```

Now I want to set a new height for the SVGs (since they all have equal height) and I want the widths to scale down accordingly. The following works for all browsers except Internet Explorer (specifically I am testing on IE11).

```
svg {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  height: 2.5rem;
}
```

On IE11 this applies the correct height but gives the SVG a width 100% of the entire list `ul`.

I've looked at tutorials for scaling SVGs, most of which focus on using SVG in an `img` and mention scaling not always working on IE but don't really give a solution that works here. Is it fixable?

Comment: Have you tried `max-width: 100%` for `svg`?

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay None of the elements `svg`, `li` or `ul` have a width set so what would the `max-width` be relative to? Maximum width of what?

Comment: my bad, yes it is worthless, well is setting the same height/width will create any issue? As I dont see any issue when I have set same height and width here at [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/80px0kpa/2)

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay In your fiddle, some of the SVGs have scaled and others haven't due to having a set width. Since they are all meant to have the same height anyway, scaling by height is fine. But when you give them set width, icons such as the Yahoo one scales more than the others.